# Adding Year and Month to a group by sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query where @BeginTime is the first day of the month and @EndTime is the last day of the month .

```
SET @BeginTime = RTRIM(@BeginTime) + ' 00:00:00'
SET @EndTime   = RTRIM(@EndTime) + ' 23:59:59'

select C.Name , COUNT(DISTINCT D.Id)  from DriverLic D 
INNER JOIN Clov C WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.CId = C.CId 

AND ((D.RDate < @EndTime) 
AND ( D.UrDate > @BeginTime))

group by C.Name
```

I get an output something like this :

```
Name  Count(D.Id)
AC        22
AB        32
CD        11
```

I would like to get an output something like this :

```
Year Month Name Count(D.id)
2013  8     AC      22
2013  8     AB      32
2013  8     CD      11
```

Is there a way i can achieve this ?

Comment: 1. Your parameters do not form part your query? 2. I suspect it is very likely you are [mishandling your date range](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), I imagine you are creating the date with a time `23:59:59` so you can use the `between` operator, forgetting that there are times after `23:59:59` and before `00:00:00`.

Comment: hey I am using the BeginTime and EndTime , I left it out of the question as I thought it would make it easy to read. I guess its causing confusion.. let me edit it to include something similar to what I have in my code.. Thank you for pointing it out.. Does this make any sense ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep,

```
SELECT Year(yourDateColumn) AS 'Year', Month(yourDateColumn) AS 'Month', C.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT D.Id)  
from DriverLic D 
    INNER JOIN Clov C WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.CId = C.CId 
--WHERE your where conditions should go here...
GROUP BY 
    Year(yourDateColumn), Month(yourDateColumn), C.Name
```

Comment: +1 The only thing I would add to this is an alias to the Year and Month Columns Year(yourDateColumn) as Year.

Comment: I do a Group By Year(@BeginTime) , Month(@BeginTime), C.Name an I get an error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: @Agent 007 Try to remove Year(@BeginTime) , Month(@BeginTime) from GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Agent007 glad I could help. You should click the checkmark near the voting, that will mark this answer as "the answer"

Comment: Hey nathan ! Sure ! I wanted to do that.. I have edited your answer so that its accurate .. Please accept my edit or due to some reason  if you cannot see it . please remove the Year(yourDateColumn), Month(yourDateColumn) in the group by clause . I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: If you remove the year & month from the group by, then the query will not work properly. You need to group by the year and month in order to combine them in the count.

Comment: hmm.. Are you sure ?? for my case having the year and month in the group by didn't work .. It gave me the error I listed above in the comment..

Comment: you used the parameters in the comment, you should use the actual `yourdatecolumn` name instead

Comment: note: you are using two different date columns in your question